# How do I reset my Playstation Network password?

Tags: psn

After the downtime with Playstation's Network, I seem to be having trouble logging in. The error message is "The sign-in ID (e-email address) or password is incorrect." What is the best way to reset the password? I don't see the option in the menus and can't find it anywhere on the web.

Comment: If you can't remember your password and you forgot your email address, can customer service use your ps3 online id to help you recover your profile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways to do it based on what information you have access to. Depending on your region, it may vary, but the instructions for resetting your password for the U.S. can be found [here](http://us.playstation.com/support/answer/index.htm?a_id=2539).

---

**Change password via PlayStation 3**

- If you know your password and know the email address associated with
  your PSN account, click [here](http://us.playstation.com/support/answer/index.htm?a_id=2542)
- If you don't know your password, but have access to the email address
  and the date-of-birth associated with your PSN account, click [here](http://us.playstation.com/support/answer/index.htm?a_id=1931)
- If you don't know your password and don't have access to the email
  address and the date-of-birth associated with your PSN account, click
  [here](http://us.playstation.com/support/answer/index.htm?a_id=2540)

**Change password via PC**

- If you know your password and know the email address associated with
  your PSN account, click [here](http://us.playstation.com/support/answer/index.htm?a_id=2541)
- If you don't know your password, but have access to the email address
  and the date-of-birth associated with your PSN account, click [here](http://us.playstation.com/support/answer/index.htm?a_id=2366)
- If you don't know your password and don't have access to the email
  address and the date-of-birth associated with your PSN account, click
  [here](http://us.playstation.com/support/answer/index.htm?a_id=2540)

---

The easiest way, however, is via the PS3 - click the "Sign In" button, and you will see a "Forgot Password?" option on that screen. From there, follow the instructions to reset your password.